# Annoying and weird regex problem: 'io\.' get's a match on the word 'function'

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, escaping

From the node REPL thing,

```
> 'function'.search('io\.')
5
```

I really need it to match only "io." and not "function" or anything with just "io" in the middle...

More weird things:

```
> 'io'.search('io\.')
-1
> 'ion'.search('io\.')
0
```

So it appears I'm not escaping the dot character..? But I am with the "\"... right ? I tested it on both http://www.regextester.com/ and http://regexpal.com/ and it works the way I think it's supposed to work.

What am I doing wrong ? Is the regex stuff in node.js somewhat different then what I'm used to ?

EDIT1: In Google Chrome's javascript console I get also

```
'function'.search('io\.')
5
```

So it might be a v8 thing... right ?

EDIT2: I get the same results from Firefox's javascript console, so it's not a v8 thing... What's happening here ? I'm really confused...

Comment: When I use the front slash, am I not escaping the following character ? I wanted to match the letter 'i', followed by the letter 'o', followed by a dot, not any character. In regexpal and that other site it works with 'io\.'...

Comment: @Oded: he included a backslash before the ., which usually escapes metacharacters.  That was obviously his intent.  Not sure why you can't see that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regex is right, but you have to encode it for putting it in a string, too.
So, your (correct) regex looks like this:

```
io\.
```

However, The backslash is also a string escape character. In order to create a string containing that regex, you have to escape the backslash:

```
'io\\.'
```

The way you wrote it, the string actually contains `io.`, which correctly matches `function`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in JavaScript, `/io\./` works as well for defining regexps without having to deal with double escaping the `\`

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that the backslash is used as an escape character at two levels: in string literals and in regexes. For example `'\\'` is the string containing a *single* backslash (which you can see if you type it into the REPL).

There are two options:

- escape the backslash: `'\\.'` is the string containing a backslash and a dot, which is a regex that matches a dot.
- use a regex literal: `/io\./`

  ```
  > 'function'.search(/\./)
  -1
  ```